# Quotation marks or no?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks

Should quotation marks be used in the following phrase?

> Have you ever asked yourself, "What will be left behind when I'm gone? How will people remember me?"

Comment: Why not? You are quoting the words of the hypothetical question.

Comment: Without quotation marks the phrasing would be different: *Have you ever asked yourself what will be left behind when you've gone? How people will remember you?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a comma needed after an italicized thought as it is with a quote?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352621/is-a-comma-needed-after-an-italicized-thought-as-it-is-with-a-quote) ... 'Notice that quotation marks and other punctuation are used as if the character had spoken aloud.

You may also use italics without quotation marks for direct internal dialogue.' // But see also [Jason's answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469912/what-is-an-indirect-dialogue-discourse/469931#469931).